# A method to pick a specific random name

Tags: c#, winforms, unique, random

I'm working on an windows app. This app contains a dynamic list of names, that are displayed in the form (user can add or delete a certain name).
What I want to do is for each name in db have another random name from the list. The only condition is that for each name should be asssigned different name and all the names must be used only once.

What I've tried to do is using a List to contain names from db and pick a random index from the List and compare it with the corresponding place in db. If it's different then remove at that index, and so on until no more names to place.

But after that I realised it's not a perfect way to do it.
Let's say, I've got 5 names,

name 1 randomly gets name 3
name 2 randomly gets name 1
name 3 randomly gets name 4
name 4 randomly gets name 2
and...
name 5 can only get name 5, so in this case it doesn't work.

Anyone has any idea how I could make it work? What other method should I use?
Number of names is about 20. Later on I will have to assign 2 different names for each name.
But at first I need to solve this problem.

Any help will be appreciated!
I'm writing in C#

Comment: What if you did a check on the count(Names) in database.  If count(Names)%2 == 0 then run your matching function (Names/2) times, else do it (Names/2 - 1) times.

Comment: Perhaps you could go back through and check for instances of duplicates (name 5 = name 5) and then randomly swap name 5's name with another name's name. Then check that name for duplicates and repeat until there aren't anymore?

Comment: Why is that result wrong? If you actually want to assign random name, you will sometimes get the same name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jan beat me to it, but here's the code I was doing to explain how you just need to switch the two last if the non-selected names match.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> names = new List<string>() { "Jeff", "John", "Joe", "Jack", "Jim" };
        List<string> otherNames = new List<string>() { "Jeff", "John", "Joe", "Jack", "Jim" };

        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 4; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int pick1 = r.Next(i);
            int pick2 = r.Next(i);
            while (names[pick1] == otherNames[pick2])
            {
                pick2++;
                if (pick2 >= otherNames.Count) pick2 = 0;
            }
            if (names.Count == 2)
            {
                // when you only have 2 names left, if the other names match...
                if (names[1 - pick1] == otherNames[1 - pick2])
                {
                    // swap one of the picked names
                    pick2 = 1 - pick2;
                }
            }
            Console.Write(names[pick1]); Console.Write(" != "); Console.WriteLine(otherNames[pick2]);
            names.RemoveAt(pick1);
            otherNames.RemoveAt(pick2);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for coding this up. I'm on a mobile browser :) +1

Answer (score 2):

Use the method you propose and Just swap the last two elements when you encounter the problem you described.

Comment: Yeap it seems easy to do so, but I will have about 20 names on the list. So what if I encounter more problems like that?

Comment: If you pick a duplicate, just pick another random name until it's a different one. If the last one is a duplicate, just swap it with the second to last...

Answer (score 0):

```
while (position == 0) {
   position = randInt() % nameCount;
}

for (int i=0;i<nameCount;i++) {
   addPair(i,position);
   position++;
   if (position>=nameCount) position=0;
}
```

Names in db are logically numbered from 0 to nameCount-1;
The idea is that you choose random position for the second name and then increment it and roll over at the end.

This is pseudocode. I don't know C#.

Great question!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273567/secret-santa-algorithm) or the answers to [ruby quiz 2](http://www.rubyquiz.com/quiz2.html) for ideas.

A basic approach might be to copy the list, shuffle the copy and line the two up.  But that can end up with the same issue you have.  But then look through the list you can swap with each self-referencing one.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would just be simpler to shuffle one `List<string> names`, create a copy, shift the copy one item down (make last item become first) and match names by position. You ensure no duplicates in one pass.